# How to load multiple arrays from a text file?

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to create a method that will take input from a file (through command line) and load the data into arrays so that I will later be able to create a table with the data (via a different method).

Here's an example text file:

```
A


1 1 1 1 1    1 1 1 1 1   1 1 1 1 1   1 1 1 1 1


B


 999 998 997 996 995     994 993 992 991 990    989 988 987 986 985    984 983 982 981 980


C


 899 898 897 896 895     894 893 892 891 890    889 888 887 886 885    884 883 882 881 880
```

However, I'm not entirely sure how to start.

What I have so far:

```
 int index = 0;

    while (f.hasNext() && index < companyCount) {
            companyNames[index] = f.nextLine();
       while (f.hasNextDouble() && index < priceTable.length)

          priceTable[index][index] = f.nextDouble();
                index++  

    }
```

I'm pretty stuck here. Not sure on how to proceed or if I have right now even makes sense.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split the strings in a file and read them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18607418/how-to-split-the-strings-in-a-file-and-read-them)

Comment: It would be handy if you could edit your question to explain your file format and what your expected result is for the given data.

Comment: The two statements after your second `while` need to be enclosed in a set of braces `{...}`; other than that, what you have here looks like a reasonable solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
int index = 0;

    while (f.hasNext() && index < companyCount) {
            companyNames[index] = f.nextLine();
       while (f.hasNextDouble() && index < priceTable.length){
          priceTable[index][index] = f.nextDouble();
                index++  
        }

    }
```

Comment: You need brackets if your code inside a loop or if has more than one command.