# How to split the string from a file?

Tags: java, android, string, split, stringbuilder

I have a simple text file with information in it called *logindata.txt* . And it looks like this:

```
username1:password1:username2:password2
```

The plan is to split the line at the " : " symbol.

This is my code so far...

```
(...)

final StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
       try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
         try {
             String line;
             while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    text.append(text);

                //stuff over here ?

                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

This works perfectly fine if my file only has one word in it.

But I want to use the file to store all the *usernames* and *passwords* (This is only for learning purposes I know it's a bit stupid) in the end like this:

(...)

```
login_button.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if (username.getText().toString().equals(text.toString()) && password.getText().toString().equals(text.toString()))

     //Stuff happening here if the username & password is correct...  

(...)
```

I'm completely stuck and have tried many examples for splitting a string and none seem to work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split the strings in a file and read them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18607418/how-to-split-the-strings-in-a-file-and-read-them)

Answer (score 1):

In your case I would like to use a `Map<Username, Password>` with Pattern like this :

```
String line = "username1:password1:username2:password2";
Map<String, String> userPass = new HashMap<>();
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([^:]+):([^:]+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
while (matcher.find()) {
    userPass.put(matcher.group(1), matcher.group(2));
}
System.out.println(userPass);
```

Outputs

```
{username2=password2, username1=password1}
```

If you want to check if the user exist or not, you can use :

```
String username = "username1";
String password = "password1";
if(userPass.containsKey(username) && userPass.get(username).equals(password)){
    //User exist
}
```

---

In case you values can be repeated you can use another structure or create a new Object which hold username and password, instead of a map

Answer (score 0):

a general code would be for splitting text would be

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String text = "username1:password1:username2:password2";
    String[] vals = text.split(":");
    for (String temp: vals){
          System.out.println(temp);
       }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To split a `String` in java, you could use `String#split(string regex)`.

In your case, after have the file read into a `String`, you could put all pairs of username/password into a HashMap for lookup.

```
String text = "username1:password1:username2:password2"; // you would read it from the file

String[] segments = text.split(":"); // split the string with ":"

Map<String, String> userPassMap = new HashMap<>(); // initialize the map to store user info

for (int i = 0; i < segments.length; i+=2) {
    userPassMap.put(segments[i], segments[i+1]);
}
```

And for your login validation

```
login_button.setOnClickListener(
     new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
             String user = username.getText().toString().trim(); // trim() to get rid of heading and trailing empty spaces
             String pass = password.getText().toString().trim();
             if (userPassMap.containsKey(user) && userPassMap.get(user).equals(pass)) {
                 //Stuff happening here if the username & password is correct...  
             }

             (...)
```