# Splitting a line to objects in java

Tags: java, file, bufferedreader

I am reading a file. I need to convert each value to java object.

```
String sCurrentLine;
BufferedReader br = null;
int pointer = 1;
try {
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("src/main/java/com/ali/trillium/p0f.log"));
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
    System.out.println("---------------");
    System.out.println(pointer++);
    System.out.println("---------------");
}
```

Output of program

```
<Tue Apr 10 09:21:42 2018> 172.20.16.36:62385 - Windows XP/2000 (RFC1323+, w+, tstamp-) (ECN) [low cost] [GENERIC] Signature: [8192:113:1:52:M1352,N,W8,N,N,S:.:Windows:?] -> 172.20.16.23:3391 (distance 15, link: unknown-1392)
```

Comment: @KamranKhan you have a lot of good suggestions in the comments. Take every topic mentioned and read up on it. I get the feeling you should spend more time learning the language. Sit down and read stuff

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18607418/how-to-split-the-strings-in-a-file-and-read-them/18607545#18607545

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split the strings in a file and read them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18607418/how-to-split-the-strings-in-a-file-and-read-them)

Comment: Kamaran Khan: Please consider selecting the only answer to this question as the selected right answer. Thanks you for your time and I hope the answer was helpful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like [Lonely Neuron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4298200/lonely-neuron) suggested :

You should use delimiting libraries in order to parse your output into a working data structure. You can use the [`split`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) function to achieve this:

```
s.split("delimiter"); // replace delimiter with the actual delimiting in the output
```

Please note that the parameter of `split` is a regex expression, so be cautious with passing things like `"."`. Assuming you have a multiple line output - you may want to use multiple calls to the `split` method.

There are numerous ways to perform delimiting in java: you can use a [Scanner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28766377/how-do-i-use-a-delimiter-in-java-scanner), or a [StringTokenizer (second answer)](https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-how-to-split-a-string/) as well.

Good Luck!